# How to check what the garbage collecter is collecting

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I am an Android developer. I got this message repeatedly. This message is not error just information. I want to know what the garbage collector is collecting (for optimization my app performance)

```
15:39:42.527  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject.demo          I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 55849(2383KB) AllocSpace objects, 153(24MB) LOS objects, 43% free, 30MB/54MB, paused 65us,49us total 151.697ms
15:39:43.662  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject.demo          I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 64582(2659KB) AllocSpace objects, 164(25MB) LOS objects, 42% free, 32MB/56MB, paused 63us,52us total 320.779ms
15:39:44.634  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject.demo          I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 57308(2367KB) AllocSpace objects, 153(23MB) LOS objects, 43% free, 31MB/55MB, paused 61us,49us total 150.726ms
15:39:45.795  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject.demo          I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 65080(2687KB) AllocSpace objects, 169(26MB) LOS objects, 43% free, 31MB/55MB, paused 70us,51us total 322.406ms
15:39:46.776  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject.demo          I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 55599(2336KB) AllocSpace objects, 152(23MB) LOS objects, 43% free, 30MB/54MB, paused 60us,49us total 152.404ms
15:39:47.945  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject.demo          I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 65083(2663KB) AllocSpace objects, 165(25MB) LOS objects, 42% free, 32MB/56MB, paused 66us,48us total 323.390ms
15:39:48.913  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject.demo          I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 59233(2451KB) AllocSpace objects, 155(23MB) LOS objects, 43% free, 31MB/55MB, paused 65us,51us total 151.311ms
```

I tried to Android Studio Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal for an Android App to periodically do the GC. Seeing from your log, it seems like you don't need to worry too much about it.

But since you asked, you can see how your app is using the memory using profiler. Specifically,

1. Launch the profiler.
2. Click the memory band.
3. Choose what type of memory you would like to record.

[image: Choose what to capture]

4. Give your profiler some time, and see the captured result. I just ran a profile for a short period of time. I'll explain my result below.

[image: capture e.g.]

In the top, total memories and the usage by components (java, native ...) is shown.
From here you can tell which part of the app is using more memory.
In my example, it's mainly native since I was running my app's camera feature during the profiling. It uses much memory during image capture / processing so it makes sense.

In the bottom is shown the list of classes, number of allocations, how "heavy" they are.

So if you see a lot more objects than you see, for example, if you expected 10 "user" instances to be active in your app but if you see 10 million, this could be a hint.

+1
Also, [LeakCanary](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/) is a good tool to help you find the memory leaks.

+2
Java's Object defines method called `finalize`, but it's generally not recommended for application developers to use it. See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--) for details.

+3
Please remember that "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

That's it. Happy coding!